# How do I delete things in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On a "create product" page, I want to delete old photos the user uploaded but never used. So, in my `new` action I want to do this:

```
def new 
  Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).delete
  @product = Product.new
  @photo = Photo.new
end
```

, any photo that belongs to the current user that has no association to a product gets deleted. However, I dont think I can just call `delete`.

Whats the proper syntax to delete those photos?

Comment: Are you talking about deleting database records, or deleting photo files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `delete` won't work, but if your `where` returns a set of records, use [`delete_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all).

```
Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).delete_all
```

[`destroy_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) works similarly, but on a higher level than just SQL, thus invoking object callbacks like `after_destroy`), etc.